# Mail template full screen on all device but not on iPhone

Tags: iphone, email, html-email

I have done my mail template, and it works on almost all devices.
Tested on:

Mail mac
Gmail mac
Gmail windows
Outlook windows

But on iPhone default mail app, the html doesn't cover all the space.
Here my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="min-width: 600px; width: 100%;" width="100%" align="center" bgcolor="#000000">
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" align="center" bgcolor="#000000">
            <tr>
              <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/logo.png" style="display: block" width="300" alt="logo.png">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/pallozzi.png" style="display: block" width="350" alt="pallozzi.png">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <h2 style="margin-bottom: 0"><i><font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">LA TUA PRIMA CONSEGNA È OMAGGIO!</font></i></h2>
                <font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">

                  (Per usufruire dell'offerta, scrivere nelle "Informazione Aggiuntive" del form "MAIL OMAGGIO")

                </font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#000000" size="2">
                  <a href="http://www.bicicouriers.it/" style="display:inline-block;background:#FFF;text-decoration:none;padding:15px;color:#000;">
                    <b>PRENOTA ORA</b>
                  </a>
                </font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/pallozzi.png" style="display: block" width="350" alt="pallozzi.png">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/pic.jpg" style="display: block" alt="pic.jpg">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#000000">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="15"></td>
                    <td align="left" width="60%" valign="top">
                      <font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">
                        Bici Couriers è un servizio di consegna in bicicletta.
                      </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="15"></td>
                    <td align="left">
                      <font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">

                        Consegniamo per voi in tutta Milano e Hinterland le vostre buste, plichi, pacchi, documenti, inviti, libri, fiori, ecc.

                      </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="15"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/pallozzi.png" style="display: block" width="350" alt="pallozzi.png">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">

                  <h2 style="margin-bottom: 0"><i><font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">SERVIZI SPECIALI</font></i></h2>
                  <font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">
                  Al di fuori delle consegne express, offriamo servizi e prezzi speciali per i nostri partners. Se possiedi un’attività locale e necessiti di un servizio di consegne contattaci ed insieme troveremo la soluzione ideale per te!

                </font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#000000" size="2">
                  <a href="http://www.bicicouriers.it/" style="display:inline-block;background:#FFF;text-decoration:none;padding:15px;color:#000;">
                    <b>SCOPRI DI PIÙ</b>
                  </a>
                </font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#000000">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                      <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/rist.png" style="display: block" alt="Ristoranti">
                      <h2><i><font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">RISTORANTI</font></i></h2>
                      <p style="padding: 0 15px">
                      <font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">
                        I tuoi prodotti arriveranno sempre in tempo e alla giusta temperatura. Grazie al team di corrieri messi a tua disposizione, i tuoi clienti riceveranno un servizio di qualità superiore.
                      </font>
                      </p>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                      <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/neg.png" style="display: block" alt="Negozi">
                      <h2><i><font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">NEGOZI</font></i></h2>
                      <p style="padding: 0 15px">
                      <font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">
                        Se gestisci uno o più negozi, ti offriamo un servizio di consegne da un punto vendita all'altro o che dal negozio arrivino direttamente a casa dei tuoi clienti.
                      </font>
                      </p>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                      <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/ev.png" style="display: block" alt="Eventi">
                      <h2><i><font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">EVENTI</font></i></h2>
                      <p style="padding: 0 15px">
                      <font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">
                        Stai organizzando un evento, un matrimonio o una festa? Ci occuperemo di consegnare gli inviti ai tuoi ospiti e di recapitare al luogo dell’evento tutto quello di cui hai bisogno.
                      </font>
                      </p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="1" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100" bgcolor="#000000">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="50" align="center">
                      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Bici-Couriers-239393376166297">
                        <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/fb.png" style="display: block" width="24" alt="fb.png"></a>
                      </td>
                      <td width="50" align="center">
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/bicicouriers/">
                          <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/inst.png" style="display: block" width="24" alt="inst.png"></a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="15">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center">
                    <p style="margin: 0">
                      <font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF" size="2">

                        © 2016, Bicicouriers<br>
                        P. IVA : 08767440962

                      </font>
                    </p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="15">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
</html>
```

I tried to add viewport, inline style on "container" table but nothing is happening.

Something missing?

Comment: If you have a moment, I have some suggestions. :)

Comment: The most important thing to add is this: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`

Comment: Did any of this answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

I applied a basic help email template that works for nearly all email programs, online and off. Try this and let me know. :)

Edit: try to avoid things like margin and padding on `<p>` elects, they won't work on every email client. Macs are super forgiving, but Outlook is hell and Gmail is is it's own set of problems.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="date=no"/>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<!--<![endif]-->
<title>BICICouriers - Milano</title>
<style type="text/css">
  #outlook a{
   padding:0;
  }
  .ReadMsgBody{
   width:100%;
  }
  body{
   width:100% !important;
   min-width:100%;
   -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
   -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  }
  v*{
      behavior:url(#default#VML);
   display:inline-block;
  }
  .ExternalClass{
   width:100%;
  }
  td{
   border-collapse: collapse!important;
  }
  .ExternalClass,
  .ExternalClass p,
  .ExternalClass span,
  .ExternalClass font,
  .ExternalClass td,
  .ExternalClass div{
   line-height:100%;
  }
  a img{
   border:none;
  }
  a {
   text-decoration:none !important;
  }
  img{
   display:block;
   outline:none;
   text-decoration:none;
   border:none; 
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  }
  table{
   border-spacing:0;
   border-collapse: collapse !important;
   mso-table-lspace:0pt;
   mso-table-rspace:0pt;
  }
  table[class=full] {
   width: 100%;
   clear: both;
  }
 div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }
  p{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   border:0;
   font-size:100%;
   line-height:1.4em;
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  h1{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   border:0;
   font-size:100%;
   line-height:1.4em;
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  #wrappertable{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width:100% !important;
   line-height:100% !important;
  }
  br[class=show]{
   display: none !important;
   max-height: 0px;
   font-size: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
   mso-hide: all;
  }
 @media screen and (max-width:600px){
  table{
   width:100% !important;
  }
  table[class=content]{
   width:95% !important;
  }
  td[class=noborder]{
   border: none !important;
  }
  td[class=hide]{
   display: none !important;
   max-height: 0px !important;
   font-size: 0px !important;
   overflow: hidden !important;
   mso-hide: all !important;
   width: 0 !important;
  }
  td[class=fullwidth]{
   width:100% !important;
   float:left !important;
  }
  /*replace image with mobile version*/
  td#pic1 img{
   content:url("") !important;
  }
  /*repeat ID as necessary*/
  img[class=fullwidth]{
   width:100% !important;
   height:auto !important;
  }
  img[class=threequarters]{
   float: none !important;
   width: 75% !important;
   height: auto !important;
   margin: auto !important;
  }
  img[class=twothirds]{
   float: none !important;
   width: 66.6666% !important;
   height: auto !important;
   margin: auto !important;
  }
  img[class=halfwidth]{
   float: none !important;
   width: 50% !important;
   height: auto !important;
   margin: auto !important;
  }
  img[class=onethird]{
   width: 33.3333% !important;
   height: auto !important;
   margin: auto !important;
   padding-top: 5px !important;
   padding-bottom: 5px !important;
  }
  img[class=quarterwidth]{
   width: 25% !important;
   height: auto !important;
   margin: auto !important;
   padding-top: 5px !important;
   padding-bottom: 5px !important;
  }
  img[class=hide]{
   display: none !important;
   max-height: 0px !important;
   font-size: 0px !important;
   overflow: hidden !important;
   mso-hide: all !important;
   width: 0 !important;
  }
  div[class=fullwidth]{
   max-width: 95% !important;
  }
  p,h1,h2[class=centered]{
   text-align: center !important;
  }
  br[class=show]{
  display: inline !important;
  }
  br[class=hide]{
   display: none !important;
   max-height: 0px;
   font-size: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
   mso-hide: all;
  }
  span[class=hide]{
   display: none !important;
   max-height: 0px;
   font-size: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
   mso-hide: all;
  }

 }
</style>
</head>

<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" offset="0" bgcolor="#000000" style="padding: 0 !important; margin:0 !important;">
 <center>
  <table width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="wrappertable">
   <tr>
    <td align="center">
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="520">
      <tr>
       <td width="518">
        <!--CONTENT TABLE-->
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" align="center" bgcolor="#000000">
                   <tr><td height="30" style="line-height: 30px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                   <tr>
                      <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/logo.png" style="display: block" width="300" alt="logo.png" class="halfwidth">
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                      <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/pallozzi.png" style="display: block" width="350" alt="pallozzi.png" class="halfwidth">
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr><td height="20" style="line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                   <tr>
                      <td align="center">
                       <h2 style="margin-bottom: 0"><i><font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">LA TUA PRIMA CONSEGNA &Egrave; OMAGGIO!</font></i></h2>
                       <font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF" style="line-height: 24px; font-size: 14px;">
          (Per usufruire dell'offerta, scrivere nelle "Informazione Aggiuntive" del form "MAIL OMAGGIO")</font>
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr><td height="30" style="line-height: 30px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                   <tr>
                      <td align="center">
                        <div><!--[if mso]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.bicicouriers.it/" style="height:60px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:150px;" stroke="f" fillcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center>
  <![endif]-->
      <a href="http://www.bicicouriers.it/"
style="background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:50px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:150px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">PRENOTA ORA</a>
  <!--[if mso]>
    </center>
  </v:rect>
<![endif]--></div>
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr><td height="30" style="line-height: 30px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                   <tr>
                      <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/pallozzi.png" style="display: block" width="350" alt="pallozzi.png" class="halfwidth">
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr><td height="10" style="line-height: 10px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                   <tr>
                      <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/pic.jpg" style="display: block" alt="pic.jpg" class="fullwidth">
                      </td>
                   </tr>
         <tr><td height="10" style="line-height: 10px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                   <tr>
                      <td align="center">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="content" border="0">
                          <tr>
            <td width="15" height="15" style="line-height: 15px; width: 15px !important;" class="fullwidth"></td>
                            <td align="left" width="60%" valign="top" class="fullwidth">
                              <font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">
                                 Bici Couriers &egrave; un servizio di consegna in bicicletta.
                              </font>
                            </td>
                            <td width="15" height="15" style="line-height: 15px; width: 15px !important;" class="fullwidth"></td>
                            <td align="left" class="fullwidth">
                               <font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">
              Consegniamo per voi in tutta Milano e Hinterland le vostre buste, plichi, pacchi, documenti, inviti, libri, fiori, ecc.
                               </font>
                            </td>
                            <td width="15" height="15" style="line-height: 15px; width: 15px !important;" class="fullwidth"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td align="center">
                       <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/pallozzi.png" style="display: block" width="350" alt="pallozzi.png">
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                      <td align="center">
           <h2 style="margin-bottom: 0"><i><font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">SERVIZI SPECIALI</font></i></h2>
           <font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF" style="line-height: 24px; font-size: 14px;">
            Al di fuori delle consegne express, offriamo servizi e prezzi speciali per i nostri partners. Se possiedi un'attività locale e necessiti di un servizio di consegne contattaci ed insieme troveremo la soluzione ideale per te!
           </font>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td height="30" style="line-height: 30px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
         <tr>
          <td align="center">
           <div><!--[if mso]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.bicicouriers.it/" style="height:60px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:150px;" stroke="f" fillcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center>
  <![endif]-->
      <a href="http://www.bicicouriers.it/"
style="background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:50px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:150px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">SCORPI DI PI&Ugrave;</a>
  <!--[if mso]>
    </center>
  </v:rect>
<![endif]--></div>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td height="30" style="line-height: 30px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
         <tr>
          <td>
           <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="content">
            <tr>
             <td align="center" class="fullwidth">
              <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/rist.png" style="display: block" alt="Ristoranti">
              <h2><i><font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">RISTORANTI</font></i></h2>
              <p style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 15px !important;"></p>
              <p><font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">I tuoi prodotti arriveranno sempre in tempo e alla giusta temperatura. Grazie al team di corrieri messi a tua disposizione, i tuoi clienti riceveranno un servizio di qualit&agrave; superiore.</font></p>
              <p style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 15px !important;"></p>
             </td>
             <td width="15" style="width: 15px !important; height: 15px !important;" class="fullwidth" height="15">&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="center" class="fullwidth">
              <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/neg.png" style="display: block" alt="Negozi" class="fullwidth">
              <h2><i><font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">NEGOZI</font></i></h2>
              <p style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 15px !important;"></p>
              <p><font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Se gestisci uno o pi&ugrave; negozi, ti offriamo un servizio di consegne da un punto vendita all'altro o che dal negozio arrivino direttamente a casa dei tuoi clienti.</font></p>
              <p style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 15px !important;"></p>
             </td>
             <td width="15" style="width: 15px !important; height: 15px !important;" class="fullwidth" height="15">&nbsp;</td>
             <td align="center" class="fullwidth">
              <img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/ev.png" style="display: block" alt="Eventi">
              <h2><i><font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">EVENTI</font></i></h2>
              <p style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 15px !important;"></p>
              <p><font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Stai organizzando un evento, un matrimonio o una festa? Ci occuperemo di consegnare gli inviti ai tuoi ospiti e di recapitare al luogo dell'evento tutto quello di cui hai bisogno.</font></p>
             </td>
            </tr>
           </table>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td height="30" style="line-height: 30px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
         <tr>
          <td height="1" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="line-height: 1px; background-color: #ffffff"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td height="30" style="line-height: 30px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
         <tr>
          <td align="center">
           <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100" border="0">
            <tr>
             <td width="50" align="center">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Bici-Couriers-239393376166297"><img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/fb.png" style="display: block" width="24" alt="fb.png"></a>
             </td>
             <td width="50" align="center">
              <a href="https://www.instagram.com/bicicouriers/"><img src="http://bicicouriers.com/application/themes/bicicouriers/assets/img/dem/inst.png" style="display: block" width="24" alt="inst.png"></a>
             </td>
            </tr>
           </table>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td height="15" style="line-height: 15px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
         <tr>
          <td align="center">
           <p><font face="Helvetica, Arial" color="#FFFFFF" size="2">
            &copy; 2016, Bicicouriers<br>
            P. IVA : 08767440962</font></p>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td height="15" style="line-height: 15px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```